# iOS Key Value Observing Xcode Project Problems

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, key-value-observing

I'm now learning key value observing, have a very simple KVO project have a little problems that dont't print property new value changes when `observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context` method called. That's very weird, hope someone help me find where problems occurred, i'm very appreciated that!

Here is my source code:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Person;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) Person *person;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Person.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize person;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.person = [[Person alloc] init];
    [self changeName];
    [self.person addObserver:self
             forKeyPath:@"fullName"
                options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                context:NULL];
}

- (void)changeName
{
    self.person.fullName = @"Andy";
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"fullName"])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", change);
        NSString *string = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
        NSLog(@"%@", string);
    }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self.person removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"fullName"];
}

@end
```

Person.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *fullName;

@end
```

Person.m

```
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

@synthesize fullName = _fullName;

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the name before you're adding the observer.  Swap this:

```
[self changeName];
[self.person addObserver:self
         forKeyPath:@"fullName"
            options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
            context:NULL];
```

...for this:

```
[self.person addObserver:self
         forKeyPath:@"fullName"
            options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
            context:NULL];
[self changeName];
```

Comment: Now i want to register dependent keys which is "fullName" in class Person. i have created another class which is Person2, it have two properties is:@"firstName", @"lastName", and "fullName" value dependent either "firstName" and "lastName" changes. I try to implement it, but don't print any values in xcode console, i want to send you the source project, can you help me look into it? Thanks.

Comment: If you have a new question, post it as a new question.

Comment: I just added a few lines code on this project test dependent keys, i send you project, can you help me look it?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the order of your calls,

You are calling `changeName` **before** you are registering as observer.

Move the `changeName` call below the `addObserver` method and see what happens.

Comment: Now i want to register dependent keys which is "fullName" in class Person. i have created another class which is Person2, it have two properties is:@"firstName", @"lastName", and "fullName" value dependent either "firstName" and "lastName" changes. I try to implement it, but don't print any values in xcode console, i want to send you the source project, can you help me look into it? Thanks.

Comment: @Andy_24 you want to implement `+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:(NSString *)key` as explained in the [KVO Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cat/NSKeyValueCoding). If you still don't understand, then ask another question.